# P2P file sharing explanation

Tags: p2p, file-sharing

I need help understanding P2P file sharing.

I know that with P2P a node request portion of files to nodes but how is the file recomposed? I mean some nodes are slower than other so I will receive the file not in order...

How are connections synchronized?

I can't find anything on internet that explains this

Comment: Here is a more technical answer to how Bittorrent handles dividing a file into "pieces": https://superuser.com/questions/219574/how-do-torrent-clients-reassemble-and-store-pieces